# How do I retrieve OuterHtml without the InnerHtml?

Tags: c#, html, dom

So I'm trying to find all matching items in an chunk of HTML. Lets use the following as an example:

```html
<body>
    <div>
    test
    <a href="test">
        <img src="test">
    </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

So we go looking for the word `test` and we find it first in the `<div>` and then in the `<a>` and then in the `<img>`.

What I'd like to be able to do is to retrieve the parent-level HTML without its attendant child-level HTML. Currently this is not attainable with InnerHtml/OuterHtml as both of those retrieve child-level markup. What I'm trying to work out is now to work through the tree of the DOM but only work at the parent-level: `<div></div>` then `test` then `<a href="test"></a>` and then `<img src="test">`.

I'm using [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) but am willing to consider anything that gives me the functionality I think I need.

Comment: Hi bugmagnet. What you're looking for is called [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) (BFS), instead of [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) (DFS). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39504040/5675325) might give some inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I posted today on [DEV](https://dev.to/bugmagnet/retrieving-outerhtml-without-innerhtml-in-c-3dn0). See the article for further discussion and an example.

```cs
private string OuterMinusInner(HtmlNode root)
{
    if (root == null)
        return string.Empty;

    foreach (var nodeFromList in
        (from node
         in root.ChildNodes 
         where node.NodeType != HtmlNodeType.Text 
         select node).ToList())
    {
        root.RemoveChild(nodeFromList);
    }

    return root.OuterHtml;
}
```